# Converting Nvarchar(MAX) to DATETIME Datatype SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm having issues converting a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to a `DateTime` datatype. I have checked for nulls and empty spaces. I'm not really sure why it isn't converting. Is it maybe because of they way it has the data in there now. If anyone could tell me what I have to change for it to work.

```
DateStamp
------------------
2015-10-1413:09:17
2015-10-1413:09:17
2015-10-1413:09:19
2015-10-1413:09:22
2015-10-1413:09:23
2015-10-1413:09:27
2015-10-1413:09:27
```

`DateStamp` is the column as you can see. Is there spaces that have to be put in or is there something else I have to change?

Comment: Im a bit new to SQL and the data i got was all from a Text file so for me to get it in first I made it a 'NVARCHAR(Max)' and then to manipulate it to what I need. I'm no expert but I try my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NVARCHAR(MAX)` strings have a missing space. For example `'2015-10-1413:09:17'` should be `'2015-10-14 13:09:17'`

As you state, this will not work when converting to `DATETIME`:

```
DECLARE @date NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2015-10-1413:09:17'
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(@date as datetime)
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime,@date)
END
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Assuming you're always going to get this datestamp string in the same format, you could use `SUBSTRING` to add the required space to the string, then convert it to a DATETIME:

```
DECLARE @date NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2015-10-1413:09:17'
BEGIN
SELECT (SUBSTRING(@date,1,10)+' '+SUBSTRING(@date,11,15)) as FormattedDate -- 2015-10-14  13:09:17 
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,(SUBSTRING(@date,1,10)+' '+SUBSTRING(@date,11,15)))
END -- Returns : 2015-10-14 13:09:17.000
```

Comment: As I pointed out on Galma's deleted answer, SQL Server can sometimes treat space-separated date/time data as if the date portion is YYYY-DD-MM and so could still fail to convert this data. Using `T` as the separator instead is never ambiguous.

Comment: I think using an ODBC timestamp is a good way of doing it, ie SELECT CONVERT(datetime,{ts '2015-10-14 13:09:17'})